# Windows Phone Emulator 8.0: No hardware virtualization detected when I do have it

Tags: visual-studio, virtualization, windows-phone-8-emulator

I just installed Vistual Studio 2013 and I get an error stating

> This computer does not support hardware virtualization, which means Windows Phone Emulator 8.0 can't run on this PC.

The problem is, that I **do** have hardware virtualization, and I'm not running this in a VM. I have Windows 8.1 Pro installed as the primary OS on my desktop, using an Intel Core2 Duo e6600. Microsoft's own "coreinfo" util found at [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722) says my CPU "Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization". I was even able to run Hyper-V on Windows 8.0 about a year ago, but since removed it.

Any idea why it's not being detected, and preventing the emulator from running?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019231/vt-not-supported-when-installing-haxm

Comment: @AlexPetrenko Nothing yet.