# VT Not Supported when Installing HAXM

Tags: windows, x86, emulation, virtualization, haxm

I am trying to install fast Android emulator which uses Intel x86 emulator accelerator.
I've downloaded the accelerator via SDK manager but when I tried to install it I got following error message in the beginning of the installation:

[image: HAXM failed]

I know that my CPU (i7-3520M) supports VT-X virtualization so I went to BIOS to make sure that it is enabled:

[image: BIOS]

As you can see, the feature is enabled in BIOS. I've found 'securable.exe' utility on the internet and when I launch it the following window is shown:

[image: securable]

Any thoughts or recommendations? I have Lenovo Z580 Laptop with Intel Core i7 and I know for sure it should support such a basic virtualization functionality.

OS is Windows 8 Pro, I also have Hyper-V enabled, I use this machine for Windows Phone 8 development.

--- edit ---

It turns out that VT-x starts working when you turn off the Hyper-V! It is very annoying because I cannot use Android and WP emulators at the same time. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

So the only solution I've found to make it work is to completely disable Hyper-V in Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Features On or Off.

If anyone knows how to enable VT-x without disabling Hyper-V please answer this question...

[image]

Comment: Same problem here. Your solution worked for me as well. Hyper-V must simply take control over the feature somehow. Thanks for figuring it out.

Comment: I was confused because I had used before WP8 emulator and I know my PC supports VT-x, but precisely because the WP8 emulator needs Hyper-V enabled this feature had remained that way and did not work the HAXM, now works!

Comment: There's a solution to keep Hyper-V enabled: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30877741/182371

Comment: Forget about working with Docker if you uncheck Hyper-V. BTW this solution worked for me too

Comment: This is the opposite what @Pavel says above https://stackoverflow.com/a/53006408/292502

Comment: My HP Envy does not have the "Hyper-V" in this list :(

Comment: @MooingDuck perhaps you have a home edition of Windows?

Comment: @AlexeyPetrenko: I do indeed have a home edition. Took me hours to figure out that that was the problem. Still working on trying to install Android emulators.

Answer (score 24):

To turn **off** Hyper-V run this from cmd: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`, and then reboot.

To turn Hyper-V back **on**, run this: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto`

Comment: I had to do this even after completely removing Hype-V from Windows Features (and rebooting, twice, since the first removal attempt failed).

Comment: I also had to do this even after completely removing Hyper-V.  This is on an 8th Gen Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon running Windows 10.

Comment: Had to do this even after disabling it, also disabling the Linux sub system, also disabling credentials management thing. Thanks a lot friend

Comment: Hafter trying everything else, did this and it worked. Thank you man

Comment: Had to do this command as well, else it didn't work, thank you :)

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem and I just found, that in Avast 9 there is an option to prevent it from using the virtualization feature. It has some impact on the Avast Sandbox, but after I disabled it, I could finally install HAXM.

Comment: This worked for me. I had Hyper-V disabled but still got VT-x not enabled error. In Avast 9 go to Settings > Troubleshooting and untick "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization"

Comment: @Nufail thanks a ton, I did everything except what you mentioned. For others, a restart is required and don't forget to disable Avast while installation.

Comment: FYI, you can re-enable hardware-assisted virtualization in avast after the installation is done.

Answer (score 7):

1. First of all you have to disable Hyper-V technology. You can do this by disabling this technology in Control Panel, Programs, Windows Functions
2. If you use Avast, disable it for the installation time. You can restore all Avast services after installation process.

I've recently had some problems with installing HAXM on my Machine (I use Dell Inspiron 5521 with Core i7 processor) and nothing helped. Finally, I downloaded this pack:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/04/25/workaround-patch-for-haxm-installation-error-failed-to-configure-driver-unknown

copied it to my HAXM folder and then started .cmd file as an Administrator. After restarting computer HAXM was installed on my computer. You can check it by typing

`sc query intelhaxm`

in your cmd.

Answer (score 6):

Hyper-V enables a hypervisor under Windows, so the OS you're running is already virtualized. VT-x is a hardware feature, so nested VT-x is not possible (without adding hardware + software support, which seems unlikely), so you will not be able to enable Hyper-V and another VT-x solution (HAXM, VirtualBox, etc) at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

For me I already had both Hyper-V and Windows Hypervisor Platform disabled in the "turn Windows features on or off".

The problem for me was the Core Isolation security option in Windows Defender. After turning that off (Windows Security -> Device security -> Core isolation details) I was able to install HAXM.

---

It's worth noting that all these issues are caused because some other application than HAXM is already using Intel VT, and it prevents multiple applications from using it at once. That other application could be Hyper-V, Credential Guard, or in my case the Core Isolation Security.

If you run `systeminfo` at command prompt, at the bottom there is a section called "Hyper-V Requirements". If there it says something like "A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed." then you know that some application is using the Intel VT and you need to figure out what that application is and disable it before you can install HAXM.

Answer (score 4):

All the suggestions above basically involve disabling Hyper-V. It's a valid approach if you're not planning to use it. But in case you do (e.g. developing for both Windows Phone and Android on the same machine etc.).

If you **need to keep Hyper-V enabled** and still use Android Studio for development and debugging, you can follow steps from [Using Android-X86 as an Emulator in Hyper-V for Windows](http://www.alteridem.net/2014/08/19/using-android-x86-as-an-emulator-in-hyper-v-for-windows/). The idea is:

1. Download Android ISO and create a Hyper-V VM off of it
2. Enable developer Developer Options, USB debugging and app installation from unknown sources
3. Connect to the Hyper-V VM image via adb
4. Launch your project from Android Studio and the VM will show up in the list of devices to connect to

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was caused by avast.

During installation I was getting 'unknown error'.
The intelhaxm service was being installed, but trying to start resulted in Access Denied.

1. I disabled virtualization support in Avast
2. I uninstalled what was left from HAXM
3. I downloaded latest installer from intel
4. I unpacked it using 7zip, unpack 64bit installer as well.
5. I restarted my PC in safe mode. I installed `HaxInst64.exe`
6. I changed *.win10_64 to *, manually installed .inf file
7. I restarted the PC into normal mode, the service was running, but HAXM still not instaleld.
8. I ran standard HAXM installer.

Done

Answer (score 1):

For now (2018) Android emulator works with Hyper-V and Windows 10 (without intel haxm), you have to check Windows version (1803+) and install "Windows Hypervisor Platform" in windows features.
All recomedations are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin

Answer (score 0):

Intel made hotfix for Windows 8.1 (HAMX 1.0.7): 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

So now you only have to disable AVAST during installation :)

Comment: Make sure you installing HAMX 1.0.7, not earlier version

Comment: I was installing 1.0.8, another requirement was to `disable` "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" in Avast and then a restart was required to get it going.

Comment: Same problem here. Trying to install 1.0.8
I have an i7-3537U processor (http://ark.intel.com/products/72054/Intel-Core-i7-3537U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz?q=i7-3537U) that supports everything the installer needs. I have disabled the "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" in AVAST and disabled AVAST completely. Still can't install. Hyper-V is active however, so I guess I'll need to disable it. Just wanted to mention that only disabling avast option and avast itself won't work.

Comment: this answer is outdated. both the link to intel and the version that the SDK downloads are 1.1.1 as of this time.

Comment: couldn't find the hotfix.  whole driver was there but it still refused to install.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

If you already disabled completely Hyper-V and it's still not working disable also:

Windows Hypervisor Platform

[image]

"The Windows Hypervisor platform is an API that third-party developers can use in order to use Hyper-V."

Ofcourse you're CPU need to be intel based and also you need to turn on Virtualization options in BIOS.

Hope it helps if not I wish you a lot of luck.