# Error during installing HAXM, VT-X not working

Tags: android, haxm

I am an entry-level Android software developer. I recently heard about HAXM that support emulator in rendering graphics more smoothly. I downloaded appropriate file HAXM file for Windows 7 64 bit, unpacked and started installing. However, during the installation process I get this error:

> "This computer meets requirements for HAXM, but VT-x is not turned
>   on..."

I checked many forum about this problem, including checking the version of BIOS and enabling Virtual Technology on BIOS. I followed the steps posted in the following forum:

[Intel HAXM installation error - This computer does not support Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat)

However, I don't have any lines about Hyperlaunch and I could not find Hyper-V options in my Windows features. I don't have any idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VT Not Supported when Installing HAXM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019231/vt-not-supported-when-installing-haxm)

Comment: I was able to fix this by running it as an admin. I had VT-x enabled and everything but running it as admin fixed it for me

Answer (score 154):

Even if you have enabled the Virtualization(VT) in BIOS settings, some antivirus options prevent HAXM installation.

*For example*: In Avast antivirus under Settings (parametres) tab > Troubleshooting (depannage), you should **uncheck**  "Enable Hardware-assisted Virtualization" ("activer l'assistance a la virtualisation").

Now restart your computer and re-install the Intel's HAXM which can be found under `~SDK_LOCATION\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`. You can also manually download the standalone [HAXM installer from Intel's website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager).

Comment: This resolved the problem I was having trying to install the HAXM executable after downloading it using the SDK Manager. My BIOS had VT enabled but the installation failed (despite saying that the computer was capable of completing the install). Unchecked the box in Avast, rebooted and HAXM could then be installed. An AVD now using the x86 android image (rather than a virtual ARM device) loads much faster and is completely slick to use.

Comment: Thanks. This saved a lot of time. How did you arrive at Avast ?

Comment: Thanks so much! This only helped. I was baffled as to what is the problem...reboot is necessary

Comment: I have quite a problem. It seems disabling it causes some real complication on the security of my pc against malware. It is showing an error that my pc could be left vulnerable. I am using Avast Premium. Any words on this?

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me hours and headaches. One question: should I check the "Enable Hardware-assisted Virtualization"  again?

Comment: Does that checkbox need to STAY unchecked AFTER installation, or can I re-enable it later?

Comment: Thanks!! This worked for me. First time i didn't finished reading that you have to restart your computer and didn't worked for me, but today i followed all the steps and then disabled temporaly Avast shields during 10 minutes to perform the installation. This must be marked as the right answer.

Comment: Thank you! For me the `Avast Setting` was at `Settings > General > Troubleshooting > Enable Hardware-assisted Virtualization`. Unchecked & Fixed it for Me. Please don't forget to restart.

Answer (score 64):

I had to enable it in my BIOS as shown below (for Asus):

[image: bios]

Comment: thank you. I'm using FW vaio laptop with win 10. Every things works fine by enabling this option at BIOS.

Comment: can you please tell me which model of Hp supports intel vtx technology

Answer (score 30):

I had exactly the same problem. And this is how I could fix it.

**Step 1:** Turn virtualization on in BIOS settings.

**Step 2:** Control Panel -> "Programs" -> "Turn Windows features on or off" (under "Programs and Features") and locate "Hyper-V", uncheck, reboot.

**Step 3:** In Avast->Settings->Troubleshooting. Uncheck "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" & "Enable avast self-defense module"

**Final step and the main:**
Go to MyPC / right click / Advanced System Settings / Advanced / In Performance click SETTINGS / Data Execution Prevention and enable DEP for all programs and services.

The last step helped me to solve this problem. Hope you too.

Comment: This is working. Don't know why but quite happy now :-)

Comment: I tried disabling pretty much every feature of my Avast installation with no success. Only after uninstalling Avast was I able to install HAXM.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me as well. I am working on both Android and WinPhone development and need both Hyper-V and VT-x enabled so I can run emulator for both platforms. 
Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution for both to work at the same time...

Comment: @pauli same for me. After uninstalling Avast Haxm installed with no trouble.

Comment: if none of above steps help in `win 11`,  disabling `MEMORY INTEGRITY` in `CORE ISOLATION` in `windows security` will help you. In [this link](https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/367#issuecomment-1111462611) i found this solution and fix the error in my computer

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issues on my notebook which runs Windows 8.1

Try this:

- Check if Hyper-V options in "Windows Features activate or deactivate" are deactivated
- Download and install the latest [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
- Reboot
- Install HAXM
- Reboot-->open BIOS--> Enable 'Execute Disable'

It looks like that the installation of VirtualBox sets a flag that "turns" VT-X on.

Comment: Where are these Hyper-V options? I don't see anything in the Windows Features dialog.

Comment: What version of windows do you use? Check out this link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857623.aspx

This option is only on Pro or Enterprise version available

Comment: Oh wait I'm using Windows 7. The problem was in the BIOS anyway (see my other answer). Cheers

Comment: In my case, I just deactivated Hyper-V and reboot. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It doe snot help. Do you think Oracle VirtualBox changes MS Windows somehow so HAXM could b installed? I am not sure...

Comment: > Had no avast > Had VT-X enabled in BIOS > Disabled HyperV. Still same error that no VMX, EPT. > Installed VirtualBox > IT *** WORKED LOL

Answer (score 5):

For Windows 10:

First of all, install the intelhaxm-android.exe located in the folder SDK\extras\Intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
if it gives error during installation then try these solution.

1. First all enable the virtualization from bios setting. To enable this, restart the computer, when the computer started then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then select the <kbd>F2</kbd> if the manufacturer is dell.
2. Even if you have enabled the Virtualization (VT) in BIOS settings, some antivirus options prevent HAXM installation.

   For example: In Avast antivirus under Settings (parameters) tab > Troubleshooting (depannage), you should uncheck "Enable Hardware-assisted Virtualization" ("activer l'assistance a la virtualisation").

   Now restart your computer and re-install the Intel's HAXM, which can be found under `SDK\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager`. You can also manually download the standalone HAXM installer from Intel's website.
3. Check that hyper-v is disabled. To disable it, go to the control panel then select the Programs --> Program and Features--> Turn windows Feature on or off (located on left side), then find the HYPER-V, uncheck the check box and restart the computer and try to install the hxm again.
4. Go to properties of "This PC" by right clicking on it, then select the advanced system setting (located on left side) then in Advance (tab) under performance click the setting button, then select the Data Execution Prevention (tab), then select this option: "turn on the DEP for all programs and services except those I select" and restart the computer and try to install the hxm.

Solution 3 works for me.

Answer (score 4):

I tried all of the above methods.  I wasn't running Avast, tried Oracle VirtualBox, and then tried to install the HAXM software from the [intel link](http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows).

None of these worked, I was still getting the same error.

What did work (and I'm not sure why) was to install another Android simulator that is available from [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com).  I was actually very surprised that it did work because during the process of creating the Android virtual device, I received an error that the Hypervisor was not turned on.  However, setup continued and the Genymotion simulator runs successfully.  Genymotion is free for personal use.

This was on a Lenova T430 laptop.

Answer (score 2):

1st. uninstall antivirus.

I had avast but I believe AVG also affects it and probably many more, just turning off the the anti virus dose not work, it has to be completely uninstalled and then the computer restarted, then run the install of the Intel HAXM, once this is complete the anti virus can be reinstalled like normal.

2nd. turn off hyper-V.

This is a setting only found on the windows Pro and enterprise, this is used to create windows mobile apps, but is you are using other software's like HAXM this needs to be off, to do this go to, control panel, all control panel items, Programs and Features, turn windows features on or off. then un-tick hyper-V

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool called [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy/download). I went to the CPU tab in Speccy and checked whether **virtualization** is  "Supported, Enabled". Originally it was "Supported, Disabled", so I went to BIOS --> Security menu and enabled virtualization. In my Lenovo Thinkpad, `F12` brings the BIOS.

Enabling virtualization helped me to overcome this error. Other answers here recommeds to check "Hyper-V" also.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got this error on my windows 11 PC.
I resolved it by the following steps:

1. Go to Windows optional features
2. Then disable Windows HyperVisor Platform
3. Then disable Virtual Machine Platform
4. Then restart twice

Hope It will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Enabling the Data Execution Prevention for all programs and services helped. I tried using the method Alex suggested above -

Go to MyPC / right click / Advanced System Settings / Advanced / In Performance click SETTINGS / Data Execution Prevention and enable DEP for all programs and services.

But I found the Data Execution Prevention page was all disabled and said "To use these settings, you must be a computer administrator and you must use the bcdedit.exe file."

This site explains how to enable DEP from cmd.
**http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-data-execution-prevention**

Comment: This resolved the problem I was having ,Thank's it really worked.Link really helped me a Lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still having issues, try running these steps from VMware to disable credential guard.  Worked for me, finally.  Steps and link are posted below, not taking credit for them.

Original content from https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2146361

To disable Device Guard or Credential Guard on Itanium based computers:

1. Disable the group policy setting that was used to enable Credential Guard.

   On the host operating system, click **Start > Run**, type **gpedit.msc**, and click **Ok**. The Local group Policy Editor opens.

   Go to **Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Device Guard > Turn on Virtualization Based Security**.

   Select **Disabled**.
2. Go to **Control Panel > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on or off** to turn off Hyper-V.  [ remove a program on Windows 8 or earlier]
3. Select **Do not restart.**
4. Delete the related EFI variables by launching a command prompt on the host machine using an Administrator account and run these commands:

   enter code here

   mountvol X: /s

   copy %WINDIR%\System32\SecConfig.efi X:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi /Y

   bcdedit /create {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} /d "DebugTool" /application osloader

   bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} path "\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\SecConfig.efi"

   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} bootsequence {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215}

   bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} loadoptions DISABLE-LSA-ISO,DISABLE-VBS

   bcdedit /set {0cb3b571-2f2e-4343-a879-d86a476d7215} device partition=X:

   mountvol X: /d

Note: Ensure X is an unused drive, else change to another drive.

5. **Restart** the host.
6. Accept the prompt on the boot screen to disable Device Guard or Credential Guard.

You should be able to install and start HAXM now

Answer (score 0):

Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWjZNqaZyqI) or try this:

- check if Hyper-V options in "Windows Features avtivate or deactivate" are deactivated
- Reboot
- Install HAXM
- go to bios and enable vt-x

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall any antivirus (Avast, in my case), reboot the system and try install the Intel HAXM again. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I Tried all above method, and none works. However I solve the problem now. Here's my trick:

In Control Panel -> "Programs" -> "Turn Windows features on or off" (under "Programs and Features") and I try to locate "Hyper-V", but I cannot locate "Hyper-V", however I have **"Windows Virtual PC"**, and I suspect they are the same thing, so I disable it, reboot, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

If your emulators were working and now they aren't due to Avast...

Avast no longer has the option for "Enable Hardware-assisted Virtualization" in Troubleshooting. (it's now March 2017)

Avast captures "emulator.exe", which disables emulators,and stows it in the Virus chest.  Open the chest, "Restore and add to exclusions" and your emulator works again...

[image: Pictorial on Avast fix]

Answer (score 0):

for Mac users, 
install the Intel HAXM kernel extension to allow the emulator to make use of CPU virtualization extensions.

The steps to configure VM acceleration are as follows:

1. Open the SDK Manager.
2. Click the SDK Update Sites tab and then select Intel HAXM.
3. Click OK.
4. After the download finishes, execute the installer.
   For example, it might be in this location:
   `sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM_version.dmg.`
   To begin installation, in the Finder, double-click the IntelHAXM.dmg file and then the IntelHAXM.mpkg file.
5. Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the installation.
6. After installation finishes, confirm that the new kernel extension is operating correctly by opening a terminal window and running the following command:
   `kextstat | grep intel`

   You should see a status message containing the following extension name, indicating that the kernel extension is loaded:
   `com.intel.kext.intelhaxm`

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#vm-mac

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue, and problem was that virtualization was not enabled by default on my machine, you need to enter BIOS setting and enable it incase its disabled. Detailed Instructions available here on how to resolve this and enable virtualization on your machine.

https://maksbay.blogspot.in/2017/12/trying-to-set-up-android-emulators-you.html

Answer (score 0):

Some manufacturers lock out the bios menu so that you can't turn VT on if this is the case there is another way to turn it on using a program called CPUID. Check out this video if this is your problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPjTFam30kc

Answer (score 0):

In Windows,

1. Open Task Manager
2. Kill QEMU(emulator system process)
3. You can able to Install HAXM installer in SDK tools
4. Start emulator(It works).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was loading haxm:
it said vtx not enable not supported
so i wasnt able to load haxm

Solution- go to your antivirus- disable virtualization setting (if it asks time 5 minutes is enough to loan) load your haxm manually and go

Comment: Others have shared better answers with more info covering much more than your answer. Why even answer when there are so many more high-quality answers?

Answer (score -1):

Did you get a message about enabling the Execute Disable bit?

You can enable the XD bit by running the following command (as administrator) and then reboot.

**bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn**

Usually, this error: "This computer meets requirements for HAXM, but VT-x is not turned on" means that your system does have Intel VT, but you need to go into the BIOS to actually enable it.

I also ran into these instructions -might be helpful to you: http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Did you ever get it to work?

Comment: This doesn't work either! After the install of VirtualBox, bcdedit "nx" is still on "OptIn" on my machine. Arcadio already checked his Bios virtualization option.

Comment: Since you are also running VitrualBox, you might find this thread helpful: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=48764.  It looks like there is a compatibility issue - only one app can use the VT resources at a time so if you have VirtualBox running and then try to install HAXM you will get an error because HAXM cannot access the resources.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.
I tried everything I found in the Internet except setting bit in CPU.
My friend suggeted me to install VirtualBox. And it works now)

Answer (score -1):

I really hated this awful problem after upgrading **Windows 10 Anniversary Update (version 1607)**. It's just about **Driver Signing Changes** in Windows 10. If you force install HAXM, you have to disable Driver Signature Enforcement too.

1. Restart W10 in Safe Mode.
2. Enter Troubleshoot.
3. Advanced options>Startup Settings.
4. Choose "Disable driver signature enforcement"
5. When Windows 10 loaded, install [HAXM latest version](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager).

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example how to do it for *LENOVA* or similar PC:

1. Start the machine.
2. Press F2 to enter BIOS.
3. Security-> System Security
4. Enable Virtualization Technology (VTx) and Virtualization Technology
   Directed I/O (VTd).
5. Save and restart the machine

Answer (score -3):

BIOS -> Overclockong -> CPU Features -> Intel Virtualization Tech -> Enabled