# Update to Android SDK Tools 23.0.5 and avd doesn't start

Tags: adt, android-sdk-tools

I am running on Windows 8.1 x64, developing Android apps using ADT Bundle. Previously (before updating the Android SDK Tools) the AVD was working very correctly and after the update, it says the following error while starting the AVD

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I tried to delete the avd, avd-folder from the windows user-specific folder and re-created the similar avd but no progress.

How can I run the avd again? (after the SDK update)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create emulator in CPU/ABI in ARM, this error only exist for Intel processor.

If you want to create AVD CPU/ABI in Intel gor for this process,
Make sure you have instaled HAXM installer on your SDK Manager.

After you download it make sure you run the setup located in: {SDK_FOLDER}\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\intelhaxm.exe

If you get the error "VT not supported" during the installation disable Hyper-V on windows features. You can execute this command dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V. You will also need "Virtualization Technology" to be enabled on your BIOS

Comment: Disabling Hyper-V in Windows Features on Windows 8.1 Pro works and IntelHAXM installed successfully.

Comment: I didn't had the Hyper-V in windows 8.1, still didn't worked. The issue was related to avast "Enable Hardware Virtualization" - disabled it and haxm installed perfectly fine.

Comment: Where can i find the SDK_FOLDER?

Comment: @Med AL The path is displayed just beneath the menu of the SDK manager.

Answer (score 13):

I've run into the same problem here and in my research I was able to find a documentation on the android  developer site that helped me out with this.

1. Start the Android SDK Manager, select Extras and then select **Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager.**
2. After the download completes, run **[sdk]/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM.exe**
3. Follow the on-screen instructions to complete installation.
4. After installation completes, confirm that the virtualization driver is operating correctly by opening a command prompt window and running the following command:

   sc query intelhaxm

You should see:

```
 SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
   ...
   STATE              : 4  RUNNING
   ...
```

Refer to this documentation here: [Using the Emulator - Configuring VM Acceleration on Windows](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#vm-windows)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had installed the IntelHAXM from the SDK Manager Extras. But at the time of installation, it says my computer doesn not  support the Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed.

Comment: Update: The same case happens with Android Studio as well

Comment: @AmitTrivedi Maybe your computer has this support but it is deactivated on your computer bios setup. Take a look at it. Or, like the doc says, look at your motherboard specification. It is hard to see nowadays a computer that doesn't have this support.

Comment: Ok @Jorge. I did enable the VT-x and XD from BIOS rather it was already enabled. I just confirmed it. I hoped that it would now install the IntelHAXM but it gave the same error. I also checked my processor on http://ark.intel.com/. It supports both, VT-x and XD. Processor model: Intel® Core™ i7-3667U Processor (4M Cache, up to 3.20 GHz).

Comment: What I found after some more research is that, it might be the problem of Operating System. But I am not sure.
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-extended-memory-64-technology-faq
It says, "Microsoft currently has two 64-bit operating systems that support Intel®64: Windows* Server 2003 x64 Edition and Windows* XP Professional x64 Edition. In addition, Microsoft released the Windows* Vista operating system in 2007, which also supports Intel®64."

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem.  I did change my BIOS and all previously, when I was running Windows 7.  Now I'm up on 8.1 and the VT-x is not supported.  Thus, apparently it does not work on Windows 8.  [Intel link.  Go down the page and it lists the Windows Operating Systems that it does support.](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/277348)

It also states that on the developer's page [Android Developer's Using the Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#vm-windows); I have been researching other options, see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635504/error-during-installing-haxm-vt-x-not-working), but when I check my BIOS it does not state "Intel Virtualization Technology" just "Virtualization Technology".  I'm not sure at this point if my computer runs this or not.  It should as it's an Intel i7.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start the Android SDK Manager, select Extras and then select Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager.
2. After the download completes, execute /extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM.exe.
3. Follow the on-screen instructions to complete installation.
4. After installation completes, confirm that the virtualization driver is operating correctly by opening a command prompt window and running the following command:

   sc query intelhaxm

You should see a status message including the following information:

```
SERVICE_NAME: intelhaxm
       ...
       STATE              : 4  RUNNING
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

FIXED

If you are having issues with the HAXM and it's not working to do what everyone else is saying to do try this:

1.Make sure you've already tried the steps above 
  (Enable Virtualization in the BIOS, as well as Uninstall and Re-Install the HAXM option from the SDK Manager)

2. Exit out of Android Studio.
3. Download and Instal HAXM DIRECTLY from Intel.
   https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager
4. Start Android Studio.

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

On Android Studio 1.3 this worked for me:

Go to Tools -> Android  -> SDK Manager

There under Appearance & Behavior -> System Setting  -> Android SDK

From there click on the SDK Tools tab

You should see Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator in the list.

Mine was not installed. I clicked the check box to install it.