# PhoneGap with Windows or iOS Emulator on Virtualized Desktop

Tags: windows, mobile, emulation, xendesktop

In reading the Adobe PhoneGap documentation they seem to have left out any information about running in a virtualized environment.

As you probably know, you cannot plug a mobile device into a virtualized desktop.  I'm not referring to a desktop that is running virtualized software like Parallels(tm) on a Mac.  I'm talking about a truly virtualized desktop running on a Linux Xen Host Server.

I'm running Microsoft Windows 2012 Server O/S on a Citrix Xen Desktop v6.5.  The host server does not support GPU nor hardware acceleration, and installing Intel's HAXM fails reporting my computer does not support this technology either.

I've found that I can only create an AVD using the ARM versions of the android emulators from the Android SDK.  And yes, they are *slow*.

I did glean some great info from : [How can I run Android emulator for Intel x86 Atom without hardware acceleration on Windows 8 for API 21 and 19?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455756/how-can-i-run-android-emulator-for-intel-x86-atom-without-hardware-acceleration).

So now that I have my s-l-o-w android emulator working with PhoneGap ... does anyone know how I can find a Windows and/or iOS emulator that PhoneGap might work with?  Is this even possible?

I see all the Windows emulators requiring the .NET framework - rather than any java SDK's and I've heard that you can just forget about iOS development on *anything* other than a MAC product.

Thanks all!

Mary B.