# My Intel Atom android emulator used to work without HAXM

Tags: android

It used to work when i first installed it.
Then I tried installing HAXM and it said my computer doesn't have VT-x (Intel Virtualization Technology).
So i looked it up and it turns out my computer doesn't support VT-x.
Now I want to run it without/ignoring the HAXM.
But it keeps giving me this error:

*emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!*

How do i just get it to run without trying to use the HAXM accelerator because i know my computer doesn't support it.

I even tried to uninstall the HAXM installer from the Android SDK manager. and it's still giving the same error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this answer from other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26369518/460557

Comment: Did you upgrade your emulator? It looks like current versions of the android emulator require HAXM for x86 guests, and I don't think there's any way to downgrade, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Fluffy is right. You now need HAXM for x86 images. I couldn't get HAXM installed either, and resorted to installing the [Genymotion](https://university.xamarin.com/resources/accelerating-android-emulators) Android Emulator. It works great and is fast and is recommended on Xamarin's website.