# unable to run android app for the second time

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device

I am new to android development. I have downloaded android studio, followed all the instructions. I could create a sample application and run it successfully.

However the problem started when I try another application or relaunch the same application, it fails to run with the errors:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

When I checked in the SDK manager, Intel x86 emulator is already installed.

Then I tried starting the AVD manually, which failed with the same error

Then I went to SDK path, and try installing "intelhaxm-android.exe" It threw error "This computer does not support Intel Virtualization..." error.

**EDIT 1:**

My system configuration:

```
Dell Inspiron 5110 4core I5 2nd gen processor with 8 GB RAM
Windows 8.1 ultimate 
I could locate Hyper-V manager showing up the system and Hyper-V is not running on this box
```

So, I believe my system is possibly ready for virtualization. If so, why I am unable to run the Intelhaxm-android.exe? Is there a setting or two I am missing. Or does my system missing any hardware to enable haxm?

Answer (score 1):

Please install Intel Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)

[image]

Comment: By this "When I checked in the SDK manager, Intel x86 emulator is already installed." I meant the same.

Answer (score 0):

closes the application from emulator and relaunch or try this [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd) and this [Update to Android SDK Tools 23.0.5 and avd doesn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353917/update-to-android-sdk-tools-23-0-5-and-avd-doesnt-start) ;)

Answer (score 0):

The SDK Manager will download the installer to the "extras" directory, under the main SDK directory. Even though the SDK manager says "Installed" it actually means that the Intel HAXM executable was downloaded. You will still need to run the installer from the "extras" directory to finish installation.

Extract the installer inside the "extras" directory and follow the installation instructions for your platform."

Comment: If I am not wrong, I mentioned this step as "Then I went to SDK path..." Is there any specific file apart from that to run to solve this issue?

Comment: Ok then, In your system BIOS go to advance setting and enable intel virtualization. If still same problem remains inatall latest virtual box [link](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)