# Android Studio - cannot create Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I just installed Android Studio and I'm trying to create virtual device.

When I try to launch the AVD in the emulator, one dialogue box pops up stating that

```
Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. VT-x is diables in BIOS. 
Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings (refer to documentation for your computer).
```

What should I do?

Comment: I too faced this issue on my Dell Vostro A840 laptop. I searched for the cause and so far found out it to be hardware issue. Intel HAXM may not be supported on your hardware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update to Android SDK Tools 23.0.5 and avd doesn't start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353917/update-to-android-sdk-tools-23-0-5-and-avd-doesnt-start)

Answer (score 0):

First Try This step 1 : 
[Enable Intel Virtualization Technology First From BIOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Wa7TGjmn5M)

Then Try this Step 2:
[HAXM installation for Android Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K9QG8VMxpt8)

I think Problem will be solved.