# Vista wont let me install HAXM

Tags: android, failed-installation, haxm

I am trying to install HAXM to use a virtual device for Android Studio, but I get the error stating "This computer does not support Intel Visualization Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed" when I try downloading it. Why?

On their site they state that the 32 bit Vista version DOES support it...
so what can I do?

I tried getting around this but using my own device for Android Studio instead, but AS isnt even able to detect my phone, even though my computer does...

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Any chance you have an AMD?

Comment: HAXM only works on intel based machines that have "Intel Virtualization Technology (Intel® VT)"

Comment: if you have an intel processor please make sure the virtualization technology is enabled in bios

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635504/error-during-installing-haxm-vt-x-not-working?rq=1  for more help

Answer (score 0):

- Cpu has to support ND/XD (execute disable) bit & Virtualization 
  (check http://ark.intel.com)
- Have to download separate installer rather than install thru Android studio
  (https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager )
- Set vt on in bios  and turn off M/S hypervisor: 
  *bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off*
- Set ND bit on             *bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn*
- Turn off antivirus  - especially Avast (Avast:  disable "Enable hardware-assisted virtualization" under: Settings > Troubleshooting)
  Then either restart the PC or do a *sc stop/start intelhaxm.*
- None of this is working try *sfc /scannow*  and reboot
- MACs need to turn down the RAM in the AVD or reinstall HAXM with lower RAM.