# I am getting the following error while running an app on android studio

Tags: android

"F:\Android SDK\tools\emulator.exe" -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable. CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

Comment: have you tried googling? The answer is foung in 18 seconds on google.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the **Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)** if you want to use the x86 emulator.

It is provided with the Android SDK, under the Extras section

Otherwise, you can use the standard ARM emulator, but it is quite slow.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, first you should make sure that Intel HAXM is installed. You could of course just try to install it (again), to make sure. 
[Download Page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)

You might encounter difficulties if you use an antivirus software. E.g. I had a problem because of avast.

> Some antivirus options prevent Haxm installation. ie: Avast : settings (parametres) tab -> troubleshooting (depannage) : you should uncheck "enable hardware-assisted virtualization" ("activer l'assistance a la virtualisation"). - [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635504/error-during-installing-haxm-vt-x-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer) where installer is in sdk/extras.

Or just disable it when create emulator