# How to solve this emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration

Tags: android-studio, windows-7, haxm

After installing android-studio-bundle-141.2456560-windows.exe in Windows 7 32 bit ultimate (6.1 build 7600)

I'm getting HAXM error while run emulator, I have exercised all the possible ways like,

1. Installing INTEL HAXM  hardware accelerator through SDK manager I have uploaded a screenshot of this.
2. I have unchecked HYPER V option in turn on and off features
3. When I try to install HAXM from android SDK extras shown in screen shot

[image]

4. Note that I don't have Virtualization option in my BIOS setup if we consider that some advanced SoC will internally takes care about this virtualization

!!!But still android emulator is throwing the error

[image]

Comment: What processor are you using on your computer? HAXM requires Vt-x which is why the emulator is failing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635504/error-during-installing-haxm-vt-x-not-working

Comment: intel core2duo E7200 @ 2.53 GHz (2 CPUS)

Answer (score 0):

According to Intel's website, the Core 2 Duo E7200 does not support VT-x

[Intel ARK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMqoD.jpg)

Unfortunately you cannot run HAXM without vt-x. This means either you'll have to try a different emulation method or use a real android device. Using a real android device will always give you the best results, so I recommend going that route.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rishub for getting me out of this confusion, can I try ARM emulation image in the above configuration

Comment: You could try emulating without haxm, but I am unsure. Try it and see :) please vote best answer if this answer was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

if you have not installed intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) then you need to install it from tools -> SDK Manager there you will find this HAXM installer

if it has been already installed then also the same issue is arising then go to the folder where SDK is stored for me it is 
D:\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
and then run silent_install with administrator permission 
and you are ready to go..!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. First, uninstall your "intelhaxm-android.exe".
2. go to the BIOS and enable "Intel(R) Virtuallzation Technology".
3. again install "intelhaxm-android.exe".
4. create a new Virtual device and run.