# Getting error about intel virtualization technology on Installing Android

Tags: android

I'm installing android studio in my laptop. But I'm getting error "System requirements meets but Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x) is not turned on."
So please tell me how to fix it?? [Error getting from Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxkvf.png)

Comment: Do you have an Intel CPU?

Comment: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html

Comment: or simply google https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=unable%20virtual%20technology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable it in your BIOS? 
Check if Hyper-V options in "Windows Features activate or deactivate" are deactivated

also you can find more answers here those two are most common problems:
[Error during installing HAXM, VT-X not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635504/error-during-installing-haxm-vt-x-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

1.Make sure your system supports VT Technology and that all VT features are enabled in the BIOS. A good utility to check your system's capabilities is: Crystal CPUID

2.Make sure the Execute Disable bit is enabled (and supported). You can run the following command as administrator: >bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn

3.Make sure "Hyper-V", a Windows feature, is not installed/enabled on your system. Hyper-V captures the VT virtualization capability of the CPU, and HAXM and Hyper-V cannot run at the same time.

4.Do you have anything else running on your system that uses VT? (Like Virtual Box?) Same issue as with Hyper-V.

5.If you have Intel cpu. Make sure you have the latest version of Intel® HAXM.

6.Sometimes this error comes because of antivirus (like avast). uninstall it. then install android studio. then install antivirus again.