# Error trying to run an emulator android studio. Gives me this error message

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, hyper-v

DISCLAIMER: I am using windows 10 and android studio 2.0.

I get this error message when trying to run an app in android studio:
"your cpu doesn't support required features (vt-x or svm)"

I've researched for a few hours now and I can't seem to fix it. The most common advice is to open the control panel and disable Hyper-v, but I the Hyper-v folder isn't there. I've also tried opening the UEFI firmware settings, same thing there it isn't even there!

Thanks for any help you can offer.

UPTDATE:
I mangaged to get into my bios (Gigabyte UEFI dualbios), however the Intel virtualization techonology isn't there, so I can't enable it. Any ideas?

Comment: may be your computer spec doesn't match, but to know this we should know what android studio version you use?

Comment: I use android studio 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem of Virtualization(VT) in BIOS settings, some antivirus options prevent HAXM installation.

This can Help you :
[Error during installing HAXM, VT-X not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635504/error-during-installing-haxm-vt-x-not-working)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've deactivted avast and as I said I cna't open BIOS. Do I need to have windows 10 pro to access the BIOS?

Comment: Settings--> update & security -->Recovery --> Restart now ---> TroubleShoot ---> Advanced options ---> UEFI Firmware Settings ---> Restart

Comment: The thing is that the UEFI Firmware just doesn't show up.

Comment: Try doing one or more of the following if you don't see the UEFI Firmware Settings button.

Disable Hibernation.
Restart the computer.
Shut down the computer, wait 5-10 seconds, and turn it back on.
Before anything appears on screen, try tapping F2 or Del buttons to pull up BIOS. 
Open [Windows logo key] + C  > Change PC Settings > General > Advanced Startup.

Answer (score 0):

in some bios it's called svm. try enabling that