# AndroidStudio: Can't run AVD because of Intel HAXM error

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, haxm

According to my AS SDK manager, `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer) version 6.0.1` is *installed*.

However, if I attempt to 'run' my app, then choose an 'available emulator' (eg, nexus one api 23), I get the error: `intel haxm is required to run this avd`.

A couple of days ago I was not having this problem (I was able to use an emulator).

Also, according to my `System Settings/Android SDK`, I have Android 6.0, API Level  23.

I am using Win XP, with AS2.0.

Comment: Have you tried to build a new AVD and see if that runs as opposed to something built a few months ago?

Comment: yes I did ... just before I wrote this post I tried again ... by the way, I installed AS just a last week, and the one emulator that I was using was installed probably 4 or 5 days ago ... i have been using a physical phone to do testing since then ... thanks

Comment: You might want to add in OS/version/machine and state that this is a relative new install to your OP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error during installing HAXM, VT-X not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635504/error-during-installing-haxm-vt-x-not-working)

Answer (score 4):

You have to install it.

Go to your sdk manager and then select it to install it (look at the bottom). Then you have to go to the folder in which the android studio is installed then look for extras/intel and then install it.

There can be a couple of problems when this happens. You have to run your BIOS to activate virtualization technology (look how to go to the BIOS), and deactivate your antivirus while its installing. (Also you should deactivate the option about virtualization technology).

When the HAXM its done, open your android studio and try to run your application, it's gonna work this time!

(I had the same problem few days ago).

Answer (score 1):

I ever see Avast! doing wrong with Intel HAXM (did you just installed it ?) on a friend's laptop.
What i would suggest is simply to unistall/reinstall it in "Settings/System Setting/Android SDK".
Personnally at the HAXM "installation" from AndroidStudio it was downloaded only. I managed by going to "C:\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager" (or the corresponding path onto your computer) in order to run the installer manually.

Comment: do you mean uninstall the HAXM, or uninstall the SDK ... and I do not see uninstall option for either ... thanks

Comment: I mean unistall the HAXM only. Check in the menu I gave you if HAXM is installed in

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you have installed Avast. You have to uncheck this option: **Enable hardware -assisted virtualization**
[image]

Comment: by 'unlock', do you mean 'check' it, or 'uncheck' it ... thanks

Comment: Sorry, i mean:Uncheck