# Error in Intel HAXM, procedure of running physical device

Tags: android, android-emulator

Installed android studio, but unable to run applications, as we need to create and select an emulator. I did it. However, I got an error message that shows-

> Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD. Your CPU does not support
>   VT-x.

Please tell me, how to use my android phone instead of emulator for testing my android applications.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091677/intel-haxm-installation-error-this-computer-does-not-support-intel-virtualizat) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635504/error-during-installing-haxm-vt-x-not-working)

Comment: Connect it with USB debugging on and,android studio will detect it. On your android device: Applications > Development > USB Debugging Then just plug in the phone to the USB. Now apps will run on your device instead of emulator.

Comment: @RRR  U are too intelligent !!

Answer (score 0):

For using your phone:

1. You have to enable developer options from your android phone by
   tapping your   build number 7 times(I guess). *Build number can be
   found in Settings -> About Phone* It will prompt you, when you start
   tapping, about how many taps are left in enabling developer tools.
2. After enabling developer tools. You can see Developer options in your settings. Head towards Developer options and enable *USB
   debugging* option.
3. Then install your mobile driver on your laptop or PC. You can find the same from your phone's manufacturer site or you can just
   google the driver which your computer is asking for.
4. Now you are done. When you run your application you can see your phone in the connected device list, click run and application
   will start running on your phone.

As far as HAXM is concerned. It increases the speed of your emulator so it is sometimes necessary to be installed on your computer so as to get speedy results.