# Android Emulator inside Android Studio too Slow

Tags: android, android-studio

The Android Emulator (inside Android Studio) that we use to run our developing app is too slow and as a consequence of that, it is very difficult for us to test the app every time, when we even make slightest changes to it.

We have changed some configurations of Emulator, updated the RAM to even 12 GB but there is only slightest change in performance in doing all those things. Can anyone help us in this regard?

Comment: switch to ubuntu. It'll work very smooth. Or use other emulators like `nox`

Comment: Genymotion is also good to use..

Comment: If you are using windows with intel processor check https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Intel Inside workstation - 2 things need to be done to improve your emulator performaance.:

1. Installing [HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)(Hardware Accelerator Execution Manager). In your Android Studio, check if HAXM is installed.

`Tool >> Android >> SDK Manager >> SDK Update Sites`

2. However, this alone will not help - For you need to enable the Intel Virtualization Technology in Bios. Check out here [how to enable the IVT](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Virtualization_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html).

If you like to have a look at how the bios settings is changed - I saw a screen grab in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635504/error-during-installing-haxm-vt-x-not-working) by @timmmm

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

use genymotion or Bluestack for emulator.these third party emulator is better performance as compare to builtin android studio emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a other emulator. Genymotion or Bluestack are good ones.

When you use the Android Studio emulators look at the RAM, to high is bad. The best setting is 2GB.

For big apps or apps that need much power I prefere my phone connected via ADB to Android Studio.

P.S.: I prefere Genymotion on my computer