# android studio AVD unknown error, HAXM already installed and VT-x is enabled

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, haxm

I got this problem after my laptop was formatted a month ago.I have already installed intel haxm and virtualization is also enabled in the BIOS, I cant figure  out whats the problem and I cant find answers.

[image]

Comment: your hyper-v is activated , just deactivate it and reboot your pc

Comment: is your PC installed with Avast Antivirus?

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try to deactivate hyper-v.

Comment: I have no Avast installed, I got Eset

Comment: try this solution it may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/36043157/6834114

Comment: @OussemaAroua Hyper-v is not activated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found out that suddenly some Windows DLL's were missing (my OS is Windows 10 64b)
I downloaded the vc_redist.x64.exe from Microsoft site (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685) and after the successful installation of vc_redist.x64.exe, my problem was solved.
Maybe this is also helping you.