# How to fix my AVD in Eclipse ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse, intel, android-virtual-device

I have been using Eclipse ADT for a while, but recently I deleted it and downloaded it again, and this time when I create AVD, it's not working.

[image: when I start the AVD which I created that's what I get!]

So I tried to find a solution and I saw that I should go to

```
sdk > extras > intel > Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
```

and install the **intelhaxm**. But I get the ***VT not supported*** error.

[image]

**I am running Windows 7 x64 Processor AMD**. The AVD used to work before. It was slow, but working. Now it is not working at all.

Comment: U can use Genymotion emlulator , it's faster

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I tried to but again I am getting this: 
Unable to create virtual device: Failed to import OVA file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Reboot the system, go into BIOS options, and make sure Intel VT is enabled
- sometimes, other virtualization software may be interfering with Intel HAXM; For example, if you have Hyper-V active, [try disabling Hyper-V in `Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Features On or Off`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019231/vt-not-supported-when-installing-haxm)

Comment: I already did the first point but still nothing changed. My processor is AMD not intel but I guess that doesn't change anything as the AVD used to work fine before. Now I don't know why this happened after deleting eclipse ADT and install it again.

Comment: @ZeeE. another option is, In your AVD manager click `Edit...` and change the image to non-x86, see if that works.

Comment: thanks @ashoke. I changed the CPU/ABI to ARM (armeabi-v7a) and it worked.