# Eclipse Android Emulator loads slow?

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, emulation

Is it just me or the emulator loads slow. I'm using Intel Atom x86 System Image. I have tried installing HAXM but got an error 'VT not supported'. The emulator is starting and running on task manager, I waited for almost an hour but it is still loading. See image-link below:

[image]

Any suggestions? This is my first time to develop Android apps.

Comment: Yes I have a solution...use AndroidStudio not Eclipse :)
Note: AndroidStudio comes with AndroidSDK

Comment: I agree with Android Studio. Try to enable 'Use Host GPU' in your Emulator functions, that might speed it up a little.

Comment: This is not emulator problem.your machine configuration is low so only  emulator not open. u config low level emulator.

Comment: If you can't get HAXM to work, then the emulator will indeed be slow as a tortoise trying to walk through a puddle of treacle. Have you looked into [possible causes of your HAXM problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019231/vt-not-supported-when-installing-haxm)?

Answer (score 1):

if you have enough RAM and good processor in your pc thn You can Use Genymotion virtual device. it is very fast and smooth. 
you can find installation instruction from here 
https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/

Answer (score -1):

you can download Genymotion ,it's so fast like phone.

Genymotion 用起来还是非常不错的哟！