# Android Studio emulator doesn't start

Tags: android, windows-7, android-studio, intel, hyper-v

I'm trying to use the `Android Studio` emulator but it doesn't work. I obtained this error message first :

[image]

Then I looked in the extras folder to install HAXM after downloading it, and I obtain this error message :

[image]

I found the advice to turn off Hyper-V on this post : [VT Not Supported when Installing HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019231/vt-not-supported-when-installing-haxm?answertab=votes#tab-top)

But I couldn't find it.

PS : My laptop is an acer with Pentium and Windows 7

Edit :

I now obtain that message :

[image]

and here is what the emulator displays :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link to know about your processor support Intel VT.

http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology

It might not supported maybe..

Or you can use Arm emulator.

Add new emulator and select armeabi-v7a System image.

Comment: My processor is a Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4500 doesn't support intel VT according to the list you gave me (found in Intel® Pentium® Processor T4000 Series for Mobile in the list). What can I do about that ?

Comment: How about Arm emulator? You can add Arm emulator at AVD Manager. select armeabi-v7a when you select System image.

Comment: Sorry I didn't find "System image" in AVD Manager

Comment: Ah...Go AVD Manager -> Create Virtual Device -> Choose device what you want and next -> You can choose system image here. Select Android version what ABI is armeabi-v7a.

Comment: Ok, I found it, now I have this message at the end of AVD:... :Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.

Comment: You have to upgrade Graphics Driver. Check your graphic card model and upgrade.

Comment: Ok, I upgraded my Graphics Driver and I have no error message no, but I only obtain a window with a black smartphone screen with android in black, I was expecting a Hello World message (I just opened a new project and didn't modify it). Should I modify my existing project to add a Hello World or does my problem come from the fact that the emulator is too slow (started more than 10 minutes ago) ?

Comment: Try again. Maybe it maybe just simple error. And If that android in black is continue forever I recommend develop with the real android smartphone. Emulator is not very good to developing... also slow in good spec computer either.. and it looks like not booting cause computer has too low spec.. There is other emulators like genymothion, bluestacks maybe you can use it. But real android device is better to developing.