# Hardware acceleration for Android Studio not working

Tags: android, android-studio, hardware-acceleration

I'm on a Hp dm4 Intel Core i5 machine with Windows 7. My Android Studio gives me the following error when I compile my application.

[image]

After some Googling I found that I have to install Intel Hardware Accelerated Executed Manager that comes with Android SDK. But when I try to do that I get this error.

[image]

Does this somehow relate to Hardware Virtualization? I already have it enabled from the BIOS.

[image]

I don't understand what the problem is. Please help!

**EDIT:** I downloaded the `Windows Hardware-Assisted Virtualization Detection Tool`from the Microsoft website and it says everything is fine. This is crazy!

[image]

Comment: What CPU do you have in your machine? What version of Windows are you running? Is Hyper V turned on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019231/vt-not-supported-when-installing-haxm

Comment: @MorrisonChang I have edited my question. I looked at the link you provided and I have tried disabling this so called Hyper-V but there is no such thing in the "turn windows features on or off" for me.

Comment: FYI android studio got nothing with it nor it needs your visualization. What  you are talking about is for android emulator.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if it's relevant. I just mentioned it to make sure.

Comment: But the issue still remains though and there is no solution in sight.

Comment: You should try http://www.bluestacks.com/ this runs smooth compare to android emulator..

Answer (score 2):

It involves two steps:

1. enabling virtualization technology : I supposed you did it right.
2. disabling hyper-V : For this , please refer the below video link:

[disabling hyper-v](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2c19WGuKjU)

If it doesn't work out please follow the blog mentioned below.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/518041

Comment: There is no "Hyper-v" option in the Windows Features. I looked very carefully in the list and I didn't find it. I have Window 7 Premium.

Comment: this is a hack, which you can try, 1)  Download and install the latest Oracle VirtualBox
 2) Reboot
 3) Install HAXM.
 It looks like that the installation of VirtualBox sets a flag that "turns" VT-X on.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualization Technology is enabled at the BIOS level means feature will be functional.
Try to check this video
https://software.intel.com/en-us/videos/setting-up-intel-haxm-on-windows

also try to go BIOS - Advanced and Enable "No Execute (NX) Memory Protection" feature.
For me after the change it's working very fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go In `BIOS` - `Advanced` and `enable` the `"No Execute (NX) Memory Protection"` feature. Hope it helps.

Comment: I checked in my BIOS and there is no option for `No Execute Memory Protection`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can use virtualization at the OS level - check it with this tool: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=592

Also, I would suggest using Genymotion https://www.genymotion.com instead of the official emulators, as it's way more faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Avast Antivirus. Disable hardware virtualization from Avast settings. Avast uses hardware virtualization to improve performance.

In Avast!, go to Settings -> Troubleshooting -> disable Hardware-Assisted Virtualization -> Reboot your machine.

--> Install HAXM

-->Enable Avast virtualization again

**It worked for me**

Comment: I'm not using Avast Antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information:
I tried to install android 9 on a virtual nexus 5 device, and the option "hardware acceleration" was not available, only "automatic".
I solved installing android 8 in a virtual nexus 6.
I still don't know if it is a problem related to android 9, or compatibility between A9 and N5, since I am a very beginner in this, but maybe this can help somebody else.