# cant install Intel HAXM with Error Failed to configure Driver:unknown error . Failed to open Driver

Tags: android-studio, windows-7, intel, android-virtual-device, haxm

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate, While installing and studio then creating AVD, This error occurs " Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module.".

Intel virtualization is enabled in BOOT Menu, While installing Intel HAXM manually - "Failed to configure Driver:unknown error. Failed to open Driver"

[image]

As directed by this site to check hyper-v is enabled https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/schadinio/2010/07/09/installing-hyper-v-manager-on-windows-7/

and downloaded-> Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 (SP1) from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887

And tried to install above software it came with the error

[image]

My processor support Virtualization and I have enabled virtualization in the boot menu.

Comment: check if you Windows Hyper-V is enabled, if yes - turn it off, then try to intal Intel Haxm

Comment: I had checked Windows Hyper-v is Enabled, so as you said i had disabled it and installed HAXM same issue came.

Comment: i had the same problem and i found the fix here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049487/vt-x-not-turned-on-haxm-error-android-studio>

Comment: This was a solution that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43721712/1658328

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. 
I tried all tricks out there, but nothing worked.

The issue only occurred when I installed 7.2.0, so I reverted back to 7.1.0 and it worked again!

Download 7.1.0 and uninstall others and install 7.1.0.

Old releases can be found [here](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases).

Comment: Not a good solutions. You should tell why this problem occurred.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. You saved my life. I searched whole internet. Saw so many solutions but nothing worked. But this one did.