# VT-X not turned on, HAXM error, Android Studio

Tags: android, haxm

I just installed the android studio on my laptop, and while running my program on  the virtual device, it gives me an HAXM error and ask to turn on VT-x.

I know that i am not the first person ask this question but I didn't found a solution. I have a intel i7 cpu with windows 10 64bit. 
1. I checked BIOS and "INTEL virtualization technology" is ENABLED. 
2. in "ANDROID SDK MANAGER" the HAXM installer option is CHECKED.

I am a beginner in android, please need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you install HAXM driver? If you just installed it via Android SDK Manager then you still need to locate this driver in Android SDK directory and install it from there. It should be in directory like `sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager` - install it by running its package from the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, I tried to install it from the path but windows is blocking the installation.

"Windows blocked the installation of a digitally unsigned driver. Uninstall the program or device that uses the driver and check the publisher's website for a digitally signed version of the driver".

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked for me, I just disabled the secure boot from BIOS and I could install it and run the virtual device in android studio. I dont know if there is a better solution because its risky to disable the secure boot.