# AVD Manager emulator not Running

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Please help me to fix the error of my AVD Manager. My Emulator is not running here is the screenshot of the error.

> Crash Service did not start and emulation requires hardware acceleration! Then also "Android Emulator requires an Intel Processor with VT-x and NX support. (VT-x in not supported).

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) it will enable you to format your question so it's easier to read and understand.

Comment: i need 10 reputation first... its okay i have solved the error tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should install package Extras -> Intel x86 Emulator Acceleration(HAXM Installer) in SDK Manager.
This might solve your problem. Kindly share your experience after trying this.

Comment: I have already install Intel x86 Emulator Acceleration(HAXM Installer) and still not working

Answer (score 0):

hardware virtualization need for running emulator please enable it in bios

Comment: please go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20019231/vt-not-supported-when-installing-haxm