# Installing HAXM gives "Failed to configure driver: unknown error. Failed to open driver"

Tags: android, installation, haxm

I am trying to install HAXM for Android development on a Dell Latitude E6510 with Windows 10. When I run the installer, I get "Failed to configure driver: unknown error. Failed to open driver".

I double-checked that Virtualization is enabled in my BIOS. I also followed the instructions given [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/04/25/workaround-patch-for-haxm-installation-error-failed-to-configure-driver-unknown) by downloading the ZIP file and running `hax_extract.cmd` from the directory in my SDK download where the HXM installer is located. I also verified that [Hyper-V is disabled](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_apps-insider_other/haxm-unable-to-installrun-on-windows-10-tech/3b88d414-a8f0-433f-bfe0-097525c92217). I still get the same error. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21066676/1440565

This answer gave me the solution. I had to disable my anti-virus software (AVG in my case) and the installation worked without any errors.